# read an input file from /res/raw (as an Input Stream)

Tags: kotlin, inputstream

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wldTB.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oahap.png)I'm new to programming and learning kotlin through CS 193a: Android App Development on youtube.
I know that it's a bit dated but I like the teaching style. Anyway...

To read a .txt file as an input stream, the method is resources.openRawResouce(R.raw.id) is used.

Before, I had to create the raw folder in res and then put the .txt file called grewords.txt into the raw folder.

so "resources.openRawResource(R.raw.grewords)"

However, the method does not find the grewords.txt file. What am I doing wrong? I've found similar issues on the internet, but non of the solutions have helped me. Is it just an outdated way of doing things that doesn't work anymore? Cheers!

resources.openRawResource(R.raw.grewords)

package com.example.vocabquiz

```
import android.R
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import com.example.vocabquiz.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.Random
import java.util.Scanner

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val defns = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
    private lateinit var myadapter : ArrayAdapter<String>





    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupList()


        binding.definitionsList.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, index, _ ->
            //
            defns.removeAt(index)
            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
      fun readDictionaryFile() {
         resources.openRawResource(R.raw.grewords)
      }

    }


        fun setupList() {
            // pick a random word
            val list = ArrayList<String>()
            list.add("Hello")
            list.add("Rob")
            list.add("BoBoBo")

            val rand = Random()
            val index = rand.nextInt(list.size)
            val word = list[index]


            // pick random definitions for the word
            defns.add("a greeting")
            defns.add("something you say when you are done")
            defns.add("a dude")
            defns.add("another name for a duck")
            defns.add("the President")
            defns.add("nothing at all")
            defns.shuffle()

            myadapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, defns)


            binding.definitionsList.adapter = myadapter


        }

}
```

Comment: That should work fine. What exactly is the error or misbehavior? Are you getting an error at runtime, or at compile time, and what is the error message?

Comment: The grewords part is marked out red and it says "Unresolved reference: grewords"

Comment: I don't see any problems. Make sure the text file has no capital letters or spaces in the file name. If that doesn't resolve it, try using the Clean Project and then Rebuild Project options in the Build menu. And if that still doesn't resolve it, delete `.grewords` from your code above, then retype the `.` and see if the auto-complete is showing you suggestions.

Comment: Cheers for your help! I did Clean Project an Rebuild Project, still no difference. I've included the auto-complete suggestions in a pic in my post, unfortunately no grewords. I've also checked there are no problems with the file name multiple times :/

Comment: I'm using viewbinding, which is not used in the orginal course. Does that change anything?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your project tree showing `res`, `raw` and the file? View binding would have no effect on this. That's just an additional optional feature and doesn't take anything away.

Comment: added the screenshot, in the link, am not allowed to post pictures yet.

Comment: Ooooooooh, I see the problem. Sorry for the wild goose chase. Will add answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
import android.R
```

You imported the wrong R class, the one that is built into Android. You need to import the one that matches the package name of your app.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what that means, but I just deleted "import android.R" and it's working, so fantastic! thank you so much!

Comment: There are multiple classes named `R`. If you don't import one, then when you use `R` in your code, it uses the one that's in your own package, the one corresponding to resources in your `res` directory. If you import one of the others, then in that file, `R` sill be interpreted as referring to the imported class instead. Sometimes you need to import your own `R` class, when you're working on code that is not in the same package as your app's package.